# Grouping optional arguments `-a`, `-b`, ... toghether using `argparse` and have `argparse` check at most `n` of them (or exactly `n`) are specified?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, command-line-arguments

> Grouping optional arguments `-a`, `-b`, ... toghether using `argparse` and have `argparse` check at most `n` of them (or exactly `n`) are specified?

Suppose I have a group of optional arguments `-a`, `-b` and `-c` and I want at most one of these (or exactly one) specified using `argparse`.

In general:

Is there some easy way og grouping these optional arguments `-a`, `-b`, ... toghether using `argparse` and have `argparse` check that at most `n` of them or exactly `n` of them are specified at the command line ?

Thanks

Comment: If `n` is actually 1, then https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion

Comment: what if `n` is arbitrary ?

Comment: Type of arguments, is tuple required(not list), maybe string or int or whatever. Specifies the types of the parameters. For single element metavar=("string",).  'N' == 'None'(my idea).Check this. http://www.psf.upfronthosting.co.za/issue21616

Comment: Would you give an example ?